# Is there a way to make a 2 dimensional array with the size from user inputs?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project that allows a user to row reduce matrices of any size, the size determined by user input. I've done this with a vector of vectors, but I can't figure out how to do it with arrays. I'm a beginner for coding, so I've only ever dealt with 1 dimensional arrays.

How can I initialize a 2 dimensional array with size from user input?

Comment: You can't.  Arrays must have a size known at compile time.  Keep using the vector.  To make it more efficent you can wrap a 1d vector in a matrix class and provide you own access to fake that the 1d vector has 2d.  example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4342498

Comment: Uh, don't like the answer linked by Nathan for abusing the function call operator as index operator – and fully disagree with the link provided there about the interface... Would rather appreciate the `[x,y]` syntax C# comes with, unfortunately that we cannot get with C++ – and `[x][y]` is next best way in my eyes (or even better?), though that requires a bit of extra work...

Comment: @Aconcagua Note multidimensional subscript operator is coming in C++23: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Uh... Tuple as index argument? Interesting idea – struggling in between the disadvantages of multiple subscripts and the need of additional braces... Well, really welcoming the proposition, though. Is it approved already?

Comment: @Aconcagua I think you’ve read the proposal wrong. Tuple as index is a workaround that is available now. The proposal meant to allow syntax like `arr3d[x, y, z]`. And yes, it’s been approved already.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep No, I didn't – was fully aware of all of these being workarounds – though never thought of using a tuple as parameter for this purpose – with the interest for only arising as for now, C++23 is still a peek into the future.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some form of heap-storage for a user-specified "2D-array" (e.g. a `vector<vector<T>>`). This is necessary since arrays have their sizes fixed at compile-time.

Because the value won't be known until runtime, there really isn't an alternative available. That said, there are two different approaches you can use with heap memory:

1. Nested containers (e.g. `vector<vector<...>>`), and
2. One container using arithmetic to produce a 2D "projection"

### 1. Nested containers

A container of a container like a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` is likely the easiest way. This is the recommended approach over manually-managed heap-allocated pointers (e.g. don't use `new T*[N]` followed by a bunch of `new T[M]` pointers. See ['Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/1678770) for more details).

This can be done easily:

```cpp
auto rows    = std::size_t{};
auto columns = std::size_t{};

// Get the input (ignoring prompts for the sake of brevity)
std::cin >> rows;
std::cin >> columns;

// using 'T' as a placeholder for the type
auto array_2d = std::vector<std::vector<T>>{}; 
array_2d.reserve(rows);

// Create 'row' number of vector objects
for (auto i = 0u; i < rows; ++i) {
    array_2d.push_back();     // create a new vector
    array_2d.resize(columns); // resize the vector to the number of columns
}
```

**Note** that this does not create a true "2d array" -- but rather it creates a container that holds `row` number of containers, each which is a container holding `column` `T` objects.

### 2. A single container, with a projection

The second way is to use a single container, such as a `std::vector<T>`, but to write a wrapper that projects a 2D array over it. For example, you could have a `get(row, column)` function that will access the element in the single contiguous `vector` and return it. This creates only 1 contiguous chunk of objects for the vector, but it's also (slightly) more complicated.

```cpp
class Array2D {
public:

    Array2D(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns)
        : m_data{},
          m_rows{rows},
          m_columns{columns}
    {
        m_data.resize(rows * columns);
    }

    auto get(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) -> T& {
        // you could also do checking here
        return m_data[row * m_columns + column];
    }
    auto get(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) const -> const T&; // can do the same for a const-qualified one...

    // Note: if you are using C++23, you can also have operator[] with
    //       more than one argument

    // ...

private:

    std::vector<T> m_data;
    std::size_t m_rows;
    std::size_t m_columns;
};
```

This would then be used like:

```cpp
auto rows    = std::size_t{};
auto columns = std::size_t{};

// Get the input (ignoring prompts for the sake of brevity)
std::cin >> rows;
std::cin >> columns;

auto array = Array2D{rows, columns};

// Get a reference to a value
auto& v = array.get(0,5);

// Set a value
array.get(0,5) = ...
```

if you want to keep an `array[row][column]` syntax, you could also implement `operator[]` to return a proxy object so that you could make the syntax behave more like a 2D array:

```cpp
class Array2DProxy {
public:
    explicit Array2DProxy(T* row) : m_row{row}{}

    auto operator[](std::size_t column) -> T& { 
        return m_row[column];
    }

private:

    T* m_row;
};

class Array2D {
    ...
    auto operator[](std::size_t row) -> Array2DProxy {
        // Return a proxy object using a pointer to the start of the row
        return Array2DProxy{&m_data[row * m_columns]};
    } 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd yet make the proxy a nested class of `Array2D` and make its pointer constructor private as well as the parent class a friend to enable it constructing one...

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row; //this is for number of rows
    cin>>row; 

    // creating array of pointer of size row
    int** arr = new int*[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int col; 
        /*
        col is the column size for each row and
        for each row column size can vary if user gives 
        different value of column for each row
        */
        cin>>col; 
    
        arr[i] = new int[col];

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            int value;
            cin>>value;

            arr[i][j] = value;

        
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please name those compilers on which this code doesn't run?

Comment: Oops, my bad. I have no idea why I misread your answer. You are of course not using VLAs. So the only issue is the non-standard header. Sorry for that. (I am not the downvoter btw.)

Comment: No problem :) For header, we can even use #include<iostream> instead of that header. #include<bits/stdc++.h> contains all the important library so that we don't need to import it explicitly

Comment: @AmitkumarSahni `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a *GCC exclusive* header that does not exist at other compilers! Don't [*ever* include it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) – not even if you explicitly target GCC (unless *perhaps* exactly one specific version), it might get abolished there with some compiler version (though admittedly not too likely...).

Comment: This solution doesn't have any specific advantage over a vector of vectors, which under the hoods does the same, but relieves you from all the necessary manual memory management – in your case you entirely missed to `delete[]` those arrays again!

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...